# Online wc-blocks-style.css rendering instead of the hosted wc-blocks-style.css

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, css

On my archive page is a sidebar which has a style I want to edit. On my local machine, the style is in wc-blocks-style.css. I edited it successfully and it renders fine. However, after deployment of the website to CPanel, the style is being rendered from an online wc-blocks-style.css. The style link is as follows:
`<link rel='stylesheet' id='wc-blocks-style-css'  href='https://c0.wp.com/p/woocommerce/6.5.1/packages/woocommerce-blocks/build/wc-blocks-style.css' media='all' />`. All other Woocommerce styles are also loaded from this online repository.

My question is, how do I make my page render the hosted wc-blocks-style.css instead of loading from that online repository? I tried looking for the header file so I can edit it there but couldn't locate where the archive product's header is.

Kindly help. Thanks

Comment: You don’t. You shouldn’t be editing core or plugin files. If you want to change the styles of something then you should add your own CSS. This could be done from a theme or in the Customiser.

Comment: Hi, Jacob. Thanks for the hint. The issue has been resolved. I located the header of my team, link the default style.css of the team and added the needed class to the style.css. That solved it. Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't need to edit the theme header to add the theme's stylesheet. Theme stylesheets are enqueued from the theme's functions file.